# Plotting matrix with map and points

Tags: r

I have a matrix A(lat,lon) that contains the values 0s and 1s.
I would like to plot a world map where the 1 have circles of dots overlaid on 
global map that is white with outlines.

I've tried some examples in I found online but I keep running into issues of 
that are beyond me. I've tried "image" but I plotted the data incorrectly and the dots were too small to see. I'm new to R and would like a simple plot to start learning how to plot maps in R, plus adding overlays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using R version: R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Pumpkin Helmet.

I've tried this code:

```
 library(maps)
 library(mapdata)
 library(maptools)
 map(database = 'world',
 xlim = c(-180, 180),
 ylim = c(-90, 90),
 fill = T,
 col = 'white',
 resolution = 0,
 bg = 'white',
 mar = c(1,1,2,1))
 points(dcn18,pch = 21,cex = 2,col = 'red')
 title(xlab = 'Longitude',ylab = 'Latitude',main = '')
 axis(1, labels = T) 
 axis(2, labels = T)
 grid()
 box()
```

This code works well and produces a nice map. But I'm not sure how to add the points, as circles, when these points are in the matrix dcn18(lat,lon) as 1's and 0's, I get only a red circle at lat 0 and lon 0. I think I need to map the lon and lat data to the dcn18 where there are only 1, collect these valid points and pass them as a dataframe to points. But I have no idea how to do this in R.

Another solution I've playing around with, comes a bit closer, but because my data has NaNs, among other issues, I think "image" is not a good solution.

```
map(database = 'world',
    xlim = c(-180, 180),
    ylim = c(-90, 90),
    fill = T,
    col = 'white',
    resolution = 0,
    bg = 'white',
    mar = c(1,1,2,1))
image(seq(-180,180),seq(-90,90),dcn18.l180, xlim=c(-180,180), 
      ylim=c(-90,90), col = heat.colors(12),fill=FALSE,
      add =TRUE)

title(xlab = 'Longitude',ylab = 'Latitude',main = '')
axis(1, labels = T) 
axis(2, labels = T)
grid()
box()
```

[image: K2pjP.png]

Comment: A small amount of code that contains your matrix and what you've tried so far would be helpful

Comment: @hrbmstr Thanks for the nudge. Now I've added some code to show where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates need to be binded together in this order Longitude/Latitude:

```
#Data Preparation: 
Lat <- c("-80", "50", "-20", "0", "20", "-50", "80" ) 
Lon <- c("-150", "-100", "-50", "0", "50", "100", "150" )

#Bind your two columns
LonLat <- cbind(Lon, Lat)

#Draw your world map here

#Draw your points on the map
points(LonLat,pch = 21,cex = 2,col = 'red')
```